# Waffle Stacking Algorithm needs improvement

Tags: java, algorithm, puzzle

I am working on a problem called Waffle Stacking. I am aware that a question already exists but the post needed to know where to start but I already have most of it done. The problem can be seen here: http://www.hpcodewars.org/past/cw16/problems/Prob20--WaffleStacking.pdf

My algorithm calculates the 120 permutations (5!) of the String "12345". I then place then row by row and make sure that they match the side clues. Then I check if it *so far* matches the top side. (Meaning that I go through the tiles that I currently have and I find the tallest stack and I look for the unused stacks and check if they are higher than the current highest stack and then I can see if I use the unused stacks they will match the clue). Using the example, my algorithm is very flawed. It produces only 4 rows and only one is correct. I believe it is due to checking the column. Any help is apprectated with checking the top and bottom sides.

```
package HP2013;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WaffleStacking
{

public static String t[];
public static String l[];
public static String r[];
public static String b[];

public static void getInput()
{
    try{
        Scanner keyb = new Scanner(new File("src/HP2013/WaffleStacking.dat"));

        t = keyb.nextLine().split(" ");
        l = new String[5];
        r = new String[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            String a[] = keyb.nextLine().split(" ");
            l[i] = a[0];
            r[i] = a[1];
        }
        b = keyb.nextLine().split(" ");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static ArrayList<String> perms = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void getPerms(String s)
{
    getPerms("", s);
}

public static void getPerms(String pfx, String s)
{
    int n = s.length();

    if (n == 0)
        perms.add(pfx);
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
            getPerms(pfx + s.charAt(i) + "", s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i + 1));
    }
}

public static void solve()
{
    int mat[][] = new int[5][5];

    for (int r = 0; r < 5; r++)
    {
        String row = "";

        for (int p = 0; p < perms.size(); p++)
        {
            if (goodRow(perms.get(p), r))
            {
                row = perms.get(p);
                for (int c = 0; c < row.length(); c++)
                    mat[r][c] = Integer.valueOf(row.charAt(c) + "");

                if (uniqueCol(mat, r + 1) && goodCol(mat, r + 1))
                    break;
                else
                {
                    mat[r] = new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}.clone();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int m[] : mat)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m));
}

public static boolean uniqueCol(int mat[][], int rStop)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < mat.length; c++)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> col = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int r = 0; r < rStop; r++)
            col.add(mat[r][c]);
        Collections.sort(col);
        for (int i = 0; i < col.size() - 1; i++)
            if (col.get(i) == col.get(i + 1))
                return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean goodRow(String row, int index)
{
    int left = 0;
    int max = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < row.length(); i++)
    {
        int stack = Integer.valueOf(row.charAt(i) + "");
        if (stack > max)
        {
            left++;
            max = stack;
        }
    }

    int right = 0;
    max = -1;
    for (int i = row.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        int stack = Integer.valueOf(row.charAt(i) + "");
        if (stack > max)
        {
            right++;
            max = stack;
        }
    }

    if (left == Integer.valueOf(l[index]) && right == Integer.valueOf(r[index]))
        return true;
    return false;
}

public static boolean goodCol(int mat[][], int rStop)
{
    return checkTop(mat, rStop);
}

public static boolean checkTop(int mat[][], int rStop)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
    {
        int left = Integer.valueOf(t[c] + "");
        int max = -1;
        String used = "";
        for (int r = 0; r < rStop; r++)
        {
            int stack = mat[r][c];
            used += stack;
            if (stack > max)
            {
                max = stack;
                left--;
            }
        }
        ArrayList<Integer> leftovers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int n = 1; n <= 5; n++)
        {
            if (!used.contains(n + ""))
                leftovers.add(n);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < leftovers.size(); j++)
        {
            if (leftovers.get(j) > max)
            {
                max = leftovers.get(j);
                left--;
            }
        }
        if (left > 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    getInput();
    getPerms("12345");
    solve();
}

}
```

Input:
2 2 3 2 1

4 1

1 4

3 2

2 2

3 2

3 2 1 3 4

Output:
[1, 3, 2, 4, 5]

[5, 1, 4, 3, 2]

[2, 4, 1, 5, 3]

[3, 2, 5, 1, 4]

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger and seeing where program execution diverges from what you expect?

Comment: The first row is the only correct row --> [1, 3, 2, 4, 5]. It starts generating incorrect rows after that. The last row is 0, 0, 0, 0 because no permutation is compatible with my matrix. Like I said, I suspect the problem lies in checking the column. So far I'm changing my code in order to implement bottom side checking. But I believe it is a lot more complicated to check compared to the top side.

Comment: Well, yes, you've said that. What I was trying to ask was if you were to try to solve the problem on paper, and use the debugger to follow along with the program, at what point does your paper work diverge from what the program is doing? So the first row matches -- but if you inspect variables and such after the first row, which ones don't match what you are expecting?

Comment: No, I didn't work or try to solve the problem on paper or use the debugger. If you are asking for which numbers didn't match, the actual output can be seen through the link provided and can be compared to my output. I believe I've worked out a solution for bottom checking which could solve the problem.

Comment: Well, that might be a good first step. Why not give it a try? It could be quite revealing. And I wasn't really asking for the numbers that don't match -- I was more thinking about the internal variables used by the program and such.

Answer (score 0):

So the first problem I see is no way to jump out when you've found a good answer. You're loops are probably continuing on after they've found the correct answer and unrolling to a point where you're losing the last row because of your else clause for a bad match.

Comment: Can you please show me where you found the continous loops, please? Because the only loop I found that seemed like it would keep going on had a break statement inside of it.

Comment: You do have a break statement but that only gets you out of the first loop. You then continue in the second loop and keep iterating. for( int r){ for(int p){ if(){break;} //break takes you to here } //not here

Answer (score 0):

Bottom side checking was not the problem, I overthought it; It should be very similar to top side checking. The solve method was very faulty and I switched to a recursive solution which ended up solving the problem. That way I can try several possibilities of valid rows while maintaining unique columns and then check if the columns were valid as well. If they weren't I can continue trying different possibilities.